# How to get details of RAID devices both soft and hard?

Tags: linux, raid, suse, software-raid

I want to check if my server has RAID configured both soft and hard.

I tried some commands on my server (Suse Enterprise Edition 11):

```
**ms:~ #  cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities :
unused devices: <none>
ms:~ #**
```

I tried to execute `raiddev /dev/md0` but there is no raiddev command available.

Is there any other command that will let me check the raid level of the server?

Comment: Please review the edited post (once it's approved). There is no need to insert <br> tags.

Answer (score 28):

Hardware and Software RAID are two different worlds. Since you mention "Server" most likely there is Hardware RAID present.

to find out use:

```
lspci -vv | grep -i raid
```

If Hardware RAID is present the output should be something like:

```
Subsystem: abcdefg RAID Controller
```

To find out more about your Hardware RAID configuration, this is only possible using your vendor specific tool. For instance, to get a detailed overview on Dell Hardware, run:

```
omreport storage vdisk
```

With an Adaptec RAID controller you can use:

```
arcconf getconfig 2
```

All vendors have their own tools. If you have a different vendor install their tool if not yet present. ([install DELL OpenManage](http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/omsa.html))

In case of Sofware RAID, for details of raid configuration use:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

and for details about RAID algorithm, chunk size, RAID level, etc., use:

```
mdadm -D /dev/mdxx
```

Comment: <6>[   17.041269] mptsas: ioc0: attaching raid volume, channel 1, id 0         What does this line means, any idea?